# Capybara - Inject a script tag and wait for async task to complete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, poltergeist

I am having  an issue with injecting script in Capybara. Here is the code snippet.

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :phantomjs_options => ['--debug=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'], :js_errors => false)
    end

    Capybara.configure do |c|
      c.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
      c.default_driver = :poltergeist
      c.app_host = "http://www.google.com"
      c.default_wait_time = 120
    end

    Capybara.current_session.driver.headers = {
      'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36',
      'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
    }
    visit('/')
    Capybara.current_session.driver.execute_script("alert('Working!');")
    sleep(1)
    system('rm /tmp/screenshot.png')
    Capybara.current_session.driver.save_screenshot('/tmp/screenshot.png')
```

Here I am injecting a script, which makes some ajax calls and changes the dom. However, when I take the snapshot, I am not able to see any changes in the page, as if the script was never there. I also tried adding a simple alert statement, but don't see the alert in the snapshot. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

`http://somescript.js` seems like a very improbable URL for your script src, are you sure that's something which resolves locally to a script?

Comment: I have replaced the scripts in the snippet with dummy URLs for confidentiality, but I am using  working URLs in my code.

Comment: What else have you replaced? Any of those could be a potential cause of the problem. Please put together a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the problem, ie. something we can run ourselves.  Show the script code, use the `alert()` if you want, then we will have some hope of being able to actually debug the problem.

Comment: Simplified the example with an alert statement now and working URLs. The issue is that I don't see the alert popup in the snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Alert, which is a **modal dialog**, will not show up in screenshots.

The reason to it is because PhantomJS is a **headless** browser that not actually rendering the whole page, in the moment screenshot is made, the whole webpage content is saved (rendered) into a file (**without the additional modal windows!**). Hence, the Alert modal will not appear at all in PhantomJs screenshots.

So, you can't screenshot an alert. What you can do, is to get the context of the alert with [onAlert](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-alert.html) handler:

```
page.onAlert = function(msg) {
  console.log('ALERT: ' + msg);
};
```

Or, if you use Capybara using a javascript driver like Selenium:

```
 alert = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
 alertTest = alert.text
 alert.accept
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about other async interactions, such as loading a js script which changes the dom. Are these changes something PhantomJS would be able to capture?

Comment: It's possible if you eject the correct event handler or event triggering inside the function that will change the dom.